# django cache query result for templates and views

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-cache

I want to `cache a query result on per request` basis. Because I need that query in multiple places. And I want to `cache` that `query` on `request` and use it whenever and wherever I want. And at the end of the `request-response` cycle it should expire . [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151469/per-request-cache-in-django) I found a solution but there is a discussion stating it would be dangerous

Can someone please tell me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151469/per-request-cache-in-django) to use per-request locmemcache instances, instead of a global cache per thread.

You could then use the middleware's process_response function to then cleanup the local cache.